# don't show google map , console error is MapsInitializer(12026): preferredRenderer: null

Tags: flutter, dart

it's my google map initialization code, when i run project dont show google map
console error :
D/MapsInitializer(12026): preferredRenderer: null
D/zzca    (12026): preferredRenderer: null
I/zzca    (12026): Making Creator dynamically
I/DynamiteModule(12026): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203115000

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Google Maps Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  static final CameraPosition initCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.hybrid,
            initialCameraPosition: initCameraPosition,
            compassEnabled: true,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't enable the Google Map service and Map SDK for android and IOS in Google Cloud Console... Try this link https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/overview

Comment: map sdk for andorid has been enabled ,its already enable for android

Comment: did u add the api key in manifest

Comment: yes brother i add api key in mainfest and also add sdkversion 20 in build.gradle.i suffer it last 2days i cound not solve this issu

Comment: try remove stack once from your code and run